# Disable Callkit Button

Tags: ios, callkit

Is it possible to disable `CallKit` buttons. like the below image-

[image]

I want to disable `keypad` `mute` etc button, that means touch will not work on this button. How can I do that. I have gone through other tutorials but I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable mute or speaker buttons, as that would provide a broken audio experience. You can, however, control a few of the other buttons. You'll want to use the CXCallUpdate object to configure your call. For example, this CXCallUpdate produces the following call screen when the incoming call is connected (the same works for outbound):

```
CXCallUpdate* callUpdate = [CXCallUpdate new];
callUpdate.supportsDTMF = YES;
callUpdate.hasVideo = NO;
callUpdate.supportsGrouping = NO;
callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = NO;
callUpdate.supportsHolding = NO;
[self.provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:callId update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {}];
```

[Example Active Callkit Call with controls disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CYHV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it, at least in iOS 10.

But if you want that buttons don't work, you can ignore notifications in your app and do nothing.

If you want in the future do anything when user press these buttons, you must override the next functions:

```
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetHeldCallAction:(CXSetHeldCallAction *)action;
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetMutedCallAction:(CXSetMutedCallAction *)action;
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetGroupCallAction:(CXSetGroupCallAction *)action;
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performPlayDTMFCallAction:(CXPlayDTMFCallAction *)action;
```